# Assigning a value if between two variables, across data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mapping

I have two data frames, one with a series of random values of length >n, call it:

```
df.my_data
```

I also have a second data frame, call it:

```
df.regions
```

`df.regions` consists of three columns, the first with a variable set of numbers 1 through n, the second with a distinguished lower bound, and the third with a distinguished upper bound. Call these

```
regions$location
regions$lower
regions$upper
```

I would like to assign the number in the first column of `df.regions`, `regions$location`, to a new column in `df.my_data` based on if the number in `df.my_data` falls between a given lower and upper bounds with respect to `df.regions`.

Let me know if I can clarify in any way.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly (and assuming that regions lower and upper bounds exhaust the range of values you need to classify and are exclusive), then this should be an analogous example

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

set.seed(1)
x = tibble(value=abs(rnorm(10, 0, 5)))
bounds = tibble(lower = c(0:6), upper = c(1:6, Inf), class = letters[1:7])

x$class <- bounds[map_int(x$value, function(z) {which(map_lgl(seq_len(nrow(bounds)), ~between(z, bounds$lower[.x], bounds$upper[.x])  ))}),3]
x
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    value class$class
#>    <dbl> <chr>      
#>  1 3.13  d          
#>  2 0.918 a          
#>  3 4.18  e          
#>  4 7.98  g          
#>  5 1.65  b          
#>  6 4.10  e          
#>  7 2.44  c          
#>  8 3.69  d          
#>  9 2.88  c          
#> 10 1.53  b
```

Created on 2019-11-24 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)

Comment: I found your answer very helpful. My reference table is from 13 - 49 (instead of 1- infinity). I want the values to return NA if the value is outside of the reference table range. How could I modify the code? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @HQL - could you be a bit more precise, maybe provide a sample of your data - see `dput` for example to provide a fully self-contained data sample that can be copied into another running environment.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem by using map2 function!